# Git refusing to perform activities with remote branch

Tags: git, macos, github

I have a git repo. I have completed the necessary procedure to setup ssh keys locally and on the repo. But, I face a weird problem. The terminal tab from where I performed the ssh setup allows me to perform normal git operations with the repo but if I try to do it from a new terminal instance it throws the following error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I have tried every possible solution on stackoverflow but the problem still persists. What could be the problem?

I am using a macOS.

Comment: I guess you could run `ssh-add` in the new terminal, and try again the git/ssh commands?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm first that you are using an SSH URL as a remote (`git remote -v` inside your repo)

Then, as commented, add the ssh key to the ssh agent, as [documented in GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) for instance.
You can automate that by [adding it to your ~/.bashrc](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows)

The [OP Aishwary Shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9890415/aishwary-shukla) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760222/git-refusing-to-perform-activities-with-remote-branch/59763605#comment105700290_59763605):

> All of this was happening because of a small typo in the config file.

I suppose it is the  ~/.ssh/config

Comment: I tried performing the provided instructions, but the error still persists.

Comment: @AishwaryShukla What command did you type for creating your private/public key? What version of Git and of openSSH are you using?

Comment: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com". I followed the instructions provided by github: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: @AishwaryShukla Can you try a new key (overriding the first, so save it first): `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM`, and register the public key to your GitHub profile.

Comment: still the issue persist

Comment: In the terminal, where the problem still persists, what is the output of `git remote -v`? (done in the local folder of the repo)

Comment: I solved the problem. All of this was happening because of a small typo in the config file. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AishwaryShukla Good catch! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.